# Unable to extract nested JSON and put into Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a JSON file and am  trying to extract a list of all teams. I can do it with one iteration, but when it's nested at more than one level, I am unable to do anything. In this scenario, I am trying to extract players into a data frame and write that to json.  Code is below. Starting with JSON. Thanks!

```
{
"teams": [{
    "coach": "Cowher",
    "players": [{
        "player": "Simms",
        "number": 11
    }, {
        "player": "Bradshaw",
        "number": 12

    }, {
        "player": "Elway",
        "number": 7

    }]
}]
}
```

Here is my Python script.

```
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
df = items_data = pd.DataFrame**(data['teams']['players'])**
```

I know in the last line is where the error is and that this is a Series. How do I get all players. Once I get this I can write this to a csv.  Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real question here, but i assume you want to know why the error occurs.

`data["teams"]` is a `list` as you can see in line 2 of your input JSON (opening square bracket).
So `some_list["players"]` does not make sense and raises `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` because a list can only be indexed by integers.

You can either get all players of a specific team:
`data["teams"][n]["players"]` where `n` denotes the n-th team.

Or you can get all players of all teams:
`[teams["players"] for team in data["teams"]]`

**EDIT:**

If you want to get rid of the nesting you can use:
`[player for team in data["teams"] for player in team["players"]]`

*note: using a generator expression might be faster, depending on how pandas works.*

Comment: My question is how do you I get all players, so that I can write a list of players to a data-frame and eventually a CSV. I have no problem when it is nested only at one level, but cannot get at when it is nested two levels like the current example.

Comment: Thanks. Extremely helpful!